# Pandas Dataframe column with both Strings and Floats

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one of the columns holds strings and floats.

The column is named 'Value' has values like "AAA", "Korea, Republic of", "123,456.78" and "5000.00".

The first two values are obviously strings, and the last is obviously a float.  The third value should be a float as well, but due to the commas, the next step of my code sees it as a string.

Is there an easy way for me to remove the commas for those values that are really floats but keep them for values that are really strings?  So "Korea, Republic of" stays, but "123,456,78" converts to "123456.78".

Thanks.

Comment: Show the date dataframe and your code.

Comment: All your values are strings. One column in pandas can only have one data type. You need two columns one for strings and on for floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, your Pandas column does not contain strings and floats, since  columns contain homogeneous types. If one entry is a string, then all of them are. You can verify this by doing something like (assuming the DataFrame is `df` and the column is `c`):

```
>>> df.dtypes
```

and noticing that the type should be something like `Object`.

Having said that, you can convert the string column to a different string column, where the strings representing numbers, have the commas removed. This might be useful for further operations, e.g., when you wish to see which entries can be converted to `float`s. This can be done as follows.

First, write a function like:

```
import re

def remove_commas_from_numbers(n):
    r = re.compile(r'^(\d+(?:,\d+)?.+)*$')
    m = r.match(n)
    if not m:
        return n
    return n.replace(',', '')

remove_commas_from_numbers('1,1.')
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
>>> df.c = df.c.apply(remove_commas_from_numbers)
```

Again, it's important to note that `df.c`'s type will be string.